# Count facebook comments doesn't work any more

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

today somehow facebook comments stopped working. :/

I had javascript:

```
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pl_PL/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=418722848267200";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

And HTML:

```
<span class="comment"><fb:comments-count href="URL"></fb:comments-count></span>
```

But I'm receiving:

```
{"error":{"message":"Top level access token or app id not specified for batch request.","type":"GraphBatchException"}}
```

Comment: Same problem on my website. May be a facebook issue

Answer (score 0):

I can propose a workaround for the following HTML block that is expected to work, but it is not working because Facebook broke something:

```
<span class="fb-comments-count" data-href="URL">0</span>
```

you can add the following script in order to make it work:

```
var $element = $(".fb-comments-count") // you can specify your selector here
$element.removeClass("fb-comments-count") // prevent fb from wrongly set this value
var url = $element.attr("data-href")
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=' + url,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (data) {
        $element.html(data[url].comments);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add the following update script in order to make it work (2017):

```
var url = window.location;
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=' + url,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data[url].share.comment_count);
    }
})
```